# Search string in text file that begins with particular word and ends with another specific word

Tags: php

I have a text file that contains various file absolute path along with other data. Now I need to write a php script to extract only the absolute file path excluding all the other text.

My file looks like

File:

```
E:\htdocs\DataSet\f1.php

Some text

    some more text

  * even more text
*

  * text again

      o E:\xampp\htdocs\DataSet\f2.php

      o E:\xampp\htdocs\DataSet\f3.php

I want to extract
E:\htdocs\DataSet\f1.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\DataSet\f2.php
E:\xampp\htdocs\DataSet\f3.php
```

Basically string/sentence that begins win "E:" and ends with ".php"

Although, the problem is simple but after searching and trying I am not able to find the solution right now...please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need regex with look ahead, this seems to work:

```
<?php
$s = file_get_contents('input.txt');
if (preg_match_all('/E\:.*(?!\.php)/', $s, $matches)) {
    $paths = current($matches);
}
var_dump($paths);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("path_to_your_data");
$pattern = '/E:.+\.php/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be work.

```
$filename = "Your file name";
$string = file_get_contents($filename);
preg_match_all("/E\:.*(?\.php)/", $string, $data);
```

Comment: Wow... I didn't notice someone have been provide an answer.